# How to use EF Core and .NET 8 to upsert into a table with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

With EF Core and .NET 8, suppose that I used the database scaffolding tool to generate entity classes that look like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new List<Role>();
}

public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

Suppose that I've written some code that looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> Create(Person entity)
{
    var roles = entity.Roles.ToList();
    Context.People.Add(entity);
    int rowsCreated = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    bool result = rowsCreated > 0;
    return result;
}
```

Suppose that I have hydrated the `Person` entity passed to the above function with data obtained by deserializing the following JSON (omitting details regarding sanitizing inputs):

```
{
    "Id": 101,
    "Name": "Sally",
    "Roles": [
        { "Id": 201 },
        { "Id": 202 }
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm having is that EF Core tries to add new rows to the `Role` table, instead of referencing existing roles. I know that in EF 6, I had to "attach" the `Role` entity classes to the context, but it isn't clear to me how to do this in EF Core.

I would like to have the ability to do this without having to query the `Role` table in the process of upserting a person.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Don't forget to show us your current SQL, and explain how it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that in EF 6, I had to "attach" the Role entity classes to the context, but it isn't clear to me how to do this in EFCore.

Not much has changed in this regard in EF Core. If you have fetched the roles than on create you can just assign them. Something along these lines:

```
entity.Roles = roles
   .Where(r => entity.Roles.Any(er => er.Id == r.Id))
   .ToList();
Context.People.Add(entity);
```

Or you can just attach them without fetching. For example with [`DbSet<TEntity>.AttachRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.attachrange?view=efcore-8.0):

```
Context.Roles.AttachRange(entity.Roles);
Context.People.Add(entity);
```

Which should do the trick.

Also note that you can [expose the join entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-class-for-join-entity) and manipulate it directly which can be sometimes more comfortable.

Comment: Why would I want to expose the join entity and have three EF classes when I have two logical things I want to work with: people and roles?  What kind of task might it make easier at the cost of having a third EF class?

Comment: @VivianRiver if a very common usecase is to manipulate the join entity itself (i.e. you have endpoints only to add or remove the person-role pairs) for example. But again - it's a matter of required operations (in the shown case potentially there is not much benefit) and preference.

Comment: This seems to work well when I add a new Person, but when updating an existing person, by adding an adding an additional role to a person who already has one role, I get an error telling me that I can't attach the role entity for the role that doesn't change because an existing entity is already attached.